# Browser Memory fluctuating while application sits idle. Why?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, memory-management, browser

I am trying to profile my application since its sluggish.I am not very versed with performance related issues. One thing that I noticed(Chrome,safari) is memory fluctuates , it increases and after some time falls even when application is sitting idle. I am not clear on why browser memory fluctuates and if it effects performance of application or its just how browser normally behaves and cannot be controlled by developer.

Thanks

Comment: how much of a fluctuation are we talking about here? some is perfectly normal.

Comment: These are the results I found :                                                                After application is left idle for 20 mins                                              Chrome - 476 MB  - 473 MB - 480MB - 481 MB - 482 MB -491 MB Safari  - 121 MB  - 131 MB - 138MB - 138.7MB -132.9MB -132.8MB -136MB

Comment: that looks like a normal amount, i wouldn't worry about it. its likely things behind the scenes being optimized and de-optimized, based on a predicted usage that didn't pan out.

Comment: So it shouldn't effect performance or count towards sluggishness of the application. I noticed though , more application sits idle in safari , its becoming more slow, reason why I thought this fluctuating memory could count bit towards this behavior.In chrome it was fine. I think I need to profile application and check heaps to see what is causing app to be slow.                                                                                               Just to understand bit more as u specified browser fluctuates memory based on predicted usage for optimization?Did i understand correctly.

Comment: browsers often partially unload tab contents if they sit idle, more stuff to a swap file, clear caches, slow down long-running intervals, and more, all of which could slightly alter the RAM footprint over time. if you notice something dramatic like the RAM doubling and halving while idle, then look into it, because it could be more than typical background operations.

Comment: These are the latest trends over the course of 20 mins app being idle(I tried to run profiler too in between(not sure if that adds memory)                                                                                                   132MB  - 132.9MB - 134MB- 137MB- 297MB-300MB - 257MB - 265MB - 247MB - 257MB - 320MB- 475MB - 519MB(steady for  10 mins)                   As seen its doubling in between and decreasing bit. Is this behaving suspiciously ?

Comment: Still stuck on this issue.                                                                     @dandavis Thanks a ton for your inputs though , got insight on how browser handles memory :)